# Is $\sum_{x=1}^n (3x^2+x+1) = n^3+2n^2+3n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I wanna check if the following equation involving a sum is true or false? How do I solve this? Please help me.

$$ \sum_{x=1}^n (3x^2+x+1) = n^3+2n^2+3n$$
for all $n \in \{0,1,2,3, \dots\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if $n=0$ is defined.  $n=1$ is clearly false.  Should that be $x=0$ in the summation maybe?

Comment: A notation cannot be *true* or *false*. It can be *right* or *wrong*. Expressions can be *true* or *false*. So, you want to check if this equality holds for all $n\in N_0$?

Comment: @Mike, for $n=0$ there is no summand, the usual convention is to define an empty sum to be $0$, the neutral element of addition. With that convention the equation holds for $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Note that it fails at $n=1$. A closed form expression for the sum is $n^3+2n^2+2n$.

**Remark:** Recall that $\sum_1^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_1^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And of course $\sum_1^n 1=n$.

Or else you can prove the result directly by induction.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1\iff3x^2+3x+1$ is the difference of two consecutive [cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Examples), so the sum will be [telescopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), since $3x^2+x+1=(3x^2+3x+1)-2x=\Big[(x+1)^3-x^3\Big]-2x$. $$\sum_{x=1}^n(3x^2+x+1)=\sum_{x=1}^n\Big[(x+1)^3-x^3\Big]-2\sum_{x=1}^nx=\Big[(n+1)^3-1^3\Big]-2\bigg[\frac{n(n+1)}2\bigg]=$$ $$=\Big[(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)-1\Big]-(n^2+n)=n^3+2n^2+2n.$$ See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples) for more information.